Media pipe pose estimated key points to blender
I extracted pose landmarks from a video and sent those coordinates to a 3D avatar in Blender using a socket. However, the avatar's movement differs significantly from the original movement of the person in the video.
Is there any formula or algorithm that we need to apply to get correct avatar movement
